# How to save Array in database - Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to store array `[3,9,21]` in database (mySQL).Other than saving the values of array, I want to save the whole array in the database. Is it possible?

Comment: not directly because mysql doesn't have arrays. You wll have to save it's string representation . Besides it's almost always better to normalize he table and store each value as a separate row.

Comment: Take a look at the [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.7+ you can; it introduced a JSON data type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

A quick read about the changes: http://lornajane.net/posts/2016/mysql-5-7-json-features

PS -- I'm a fan of the comment above -- storing values as separate rows instead of as arrays is a better option

Comment: If you need to reference these values in a `JOIN` or a `WHERE` clause, yes, you absolutely do need to break them out into a proper relational structure. That's not always the case, and sometimes serializing as JSON is actually more convenient.

Comment: You should store each item as a row. Keep your data organized will be much cleaner.